# How to display common values in EXCEL?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to display common values from columns?

[image: Example of entered data in columns]

I would like to display common values in a different sheet. For example, the letter "a" is common in columns 1,2,and 4.

[image: Common Values]

Comment: Can you step back and explain what you're trying to achieve in the context of the workbook? I have a feeling that you may ask about Problem X when you really want to solve Problem Y.

Comment: I would like to display all the common values from the columns. As in the example, the letter "a" appears in columns 1, 2, and 4. As another example, if we were to look at the letter "c", it appears in only columns 1 and 4.

Comment: define what "common" is for you in this context. This is not distinctly clear (just hinted on) from what you have now...

Comment: I understood your question perfectly. I just want to learn more about the practical use case that you want to apply it to. It's not about letter "a". What are you trying to achieve in real life??

Comment: Ok, got it. I have a list of stores and brands that each store carries. I would then like to display the brands, and underneath that, I would like to see the list of stores. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Is Power Query an option? Fairly straightforward it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `Power Query` (aka `Get & Transform`), it is fairly straightforward.

- Select some cell in the table
- `Data => Get & Transform => from Table/Range`
- In the `Power Query` UI, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor` and replace the code you see there with the code below.
- To understand what is going on, select the steps in the `Applied Steps` window and observe the results. Also read the comments within the code

The major steps are to

- Unpivot the columns resulting in a two column table.
- then Group by "Brand" and extract the resulting "stores"
- Finally transpose the table so the "stores" become the column headers.

There is various code added manually so as to easily account for adding/subtracting rows and columns and avoid having to use fixed column names.

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="brandsTbl"]}[Content],

//Unpivot => 2 columns
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {}, "Store", "Brand"),


    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Columns", {"Brand"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Store=text, Brand=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each List.Sort(Table.Column([Grouped],"Store"))),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Grouped"}),
    
//Add column so we can tell how many columns we will need to split the results into
    colCount = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Count", each List.Count([Custom])),

#"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ";"), type text}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv),
      List.Max(Table.Column(colCount,"Count"))),
    
    
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Brand", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Sorted Rows"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    
//change all columns to type text
colNames = Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"),
changeTypeList = List.Zip({colNames,List.Repeat({type text}, List.Count(colNames))}),
    
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers", changeTypeList)
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

[image]

Comment: Ron, thank you for this! The result that you show is exactly what I am trying to achieve. I followed the steps you provided however, I am stuck when trying to do the "major steps" you provided. If possible, can you provide some detail on how to accomplish these steps: 

Unpivot the columns resulting in a two column table.
then Group by "Brand" and extract the resulting "stores"
Finally transpose the table so the "stores" become the column headers.

Comment: @user4031385 If you just paste the code I show into the Advanced Editor, in place of whatever may be there, and change the table name in Line 2 to match the table name in your workbook, you should be able to examine the steps in the Applied Steps window.

Comment: Yes, I pasted the code and then brought up the Advanced Editor. I also see the Applied Steps window, but I am not clear on what I should be doing there exactly.

Comment: @user4031385 First bring up the Advanced Editor.  Then Paste the code. Are you seeing the same results I show?  If you are, you don't need to do anything.  Examining the applied steps, and any comments, will provide an understanding of what's going on.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I am seeing the same result as yours, except that the headers have drop-down arrow (not a bid deal, but just curious why mine shows that). Thanks again for the help! And lastly, will this update automatically if I make edits to it or will I have to do the same process to get updated results?

Comment: @user4031385 In order to update, after you make a change in your data table, you need to **Refresh** the query.  This can be done from the Queries and Connections window if it is open; or from the main menu; `Data => Queries and Connections =>Refresh`. Or you could create a button; or possibly with a worksheet change event. You shouldn't have to do anything other than the Refresh.

Comment: @user4031385 The automatic drop-down arrows is something that seems to happen with all Tables. I don't know of a setting to avoid it.  I remove them manually by, after selecting a cell in the table, I navigate to `Table Design => Filter Button` and deselect.  Once you've removed it, they should stay removed.